# Magento 2.3 - php 7.2.10 - Reindex error - bin/magento is not opening -

Tags: reindex, magento2.3, bin-magento

MacOS High Sierra
MAMP php webserver - 7.2.10

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin//php- 7.2.10

 -- usr/bin/php - 7.1.16




Nittns-MacBook-Air:~ baanallc$ cd /applications/MAMP/htdocs/23/

Nittns-MacBook-Air:23 baanallc$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex

In Abstract.php line 144:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In Abstract.php line 128:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


indexer:reindex [<index>...]
```

Please advise, how can I reindex magento2 on localhost MAMP?

Comment: looks like mysql is not started yet. Try to restart xampp or mamp

Comment: change from DB_HOST=localhost to DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 at .env file and try it by clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out the way. I had 3 PHP installed

1. /usr/bin/php ----------------------------- **macOS default php 7.1**
2. /usr/local/cellar/php/7.2.12_2/bin/php ---- **Home-brew php 7.2**
3. /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/php -**-MAMP php**

> **-------did following changes and indexes and cron jobs worked like magic.-----**

1. Changed the directory to Magento home dir ------(use your Magento install dir)

   **`$ cd /applications/MAMP/htdocs/23/`**
2. Changed PHP PATH to same as being used by Magento --(use Path of PHP used for Magento web server)

   **`$ export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/:$PATH`**

Answer (score 0):

try to change the hostname:

```
 From 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in app/etc/env.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam also facing the same error while run the Flush the Cache and Reindex commands. I have found the issue was my MySQL server got stop.

Everything is working fine after Restart the MySql in my Server.